# Fix layout such that no rearrange of content happens

Tags: html, css, dom

I am trying to fix the web layout of my web page such that it does not resize or rearrange .
for example , check the page at http://www.boutell.com/newfaq/creating/fixedwidthlayout.html
. On my browser(chrome), when i resize the window along x-axis, the text rearranges to accomodate within viewable area.

On the other hand, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/dn255008(v=vs.85).aspx

when i resize the window along x-axis, the text does not rearrange to accomodate itself.  I need my web page to NOT rearrange as in the latter case. Not able to isolate the attribute which controls this. I tried position:absolute in the body tag. No luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a fluid layout. All your columns have their width set in percents. So, when the browser size changes, the columns's width changes too. Lets say one of your container has a width of 15%. When the browser window width is 2000px, this container's size will be counted as 15% from 2000px = 300px; on the other device, where width is 1200px, it will be 180px.

- The fastest way to fix it to change width to px;
- Another way is to set `min-width` property, - then the container can 
  act as a fluid, but at some point it won't go smaller. For example:

  .columnt {
     width: 15%;
     min-width: 200px;
  }

Hope you get the idea.